# SMTP starttls / ssl / auth combinations

Tags: email, ssl

Part of our app allows users to input their SMTP server info for sending emails, and users are always coming up with combinations we aren't set up to test. Specifically, looking at these Java mail props: mail.smtp.auth, mail.smtp.starttls.enable, and mail.smtp.ssl.enable.

Are all 8 combinations valid? (Valid as in there could be some server somewhere that requires that combination -- I already know Java will let me set any of these) If not, which would not be valid combinations? Bonus points for links to where this is documented -- my googlefu has failed me on this.